# Use same resource for languages with different IETF language tag in i18next

Tags: i18next, react-i18next

I have the following code:

```
import i18n from 'i18next'

import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next'
import locales from 'locales'

const resources = {
  en: locales.en,
  no: locales.no,
  de: locales.de,
  se: locales.se
}

function getDefaultLocale() {
  const preferredLanguage = localStorage.getItem('preferredLanguage')
  const lng = locales.languages
    .map(({ code }) => code)
    .find(code =>
      code === preferredLanguage || // The user has set a preferred language
        code === '__DEFAULT_LOCALE__' || // Default locale set at build time.
        code === navigator.language
    )
  return lng
}

i18n
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    resources,
    lng: getDefaultLocale(),
    appendNamespaceToCIMode: true
  })

export default i18n
```

My problem is, that let's say when the English language is detected with `navigator.language`, it may be `en`, `en-US`, `en-GB`, or for Norwegian, it may be `nb`, `nb-NO`, `ny-NO` etc.

We would like to serve the same translations for all English language codes, and the same for all the Norwegian language codes.

My current solution is to defined resources like so:

```
const resources = {
  en: locales.en,
  'en-US': locales.en,
  'en-GB': locales.en,
  no: locales.no,
  'nb-NO': locales.no,
  'ny-NO': locales.no,
  de: locales.de,
  se: locales.se
}
```

But there must be a better solution to this! Could someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Default behaviour for locales containing region is to fallback to the primary language code.

For instance, we have detected `en-GB`, but there is not translation file assigned to this locale. Assuming that `en` translations are in place, expected behaviour would be to proceed with them, not causing any trouble.

This practically means you can remove duplicate declaration from your initialization code:

```js
const resources = {
  en: locales.en,
  no: locales.no,
  de: locales.de,
  se: locales.se
}
```

If you prefer, it could be done in a more concise manner:

```js
const resources = { ...locales }
```